# Select values from a dictionary on the condition that their keys fit into a pattern

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

Given a dictionary like

```
dic = {
    'AB': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'ABA': ['e', 'f', 'g'],
    'BA': ['h', 'i', 'j'],
    'BAB': ['k', 'l'], ...
 
}
```

I would like to write a function that randomly selects the values from the dictionary so that their keys together match a pattern that is defined by input arguments.

```
def match_pattern(source, time, feature):
    pattern = feature * time
    ...
```

so, `match_pattern(dic, 4, 'AB')` will randomly return results like

['a', 'f', 'l'], or

['f', 'k', 'd'], or

['d', 'd', 'a', 'c'] ...

They fit into the pattern 'ABABABAB'.

Notes:

Sorry for some unclearness.

The actual dictionary is very large, and there will be restrictions on what can be input as the arguments, so there will be enough values to select.

Because the lengths of the keys are different, so the length of the returned list may also be different. You can have 3 or 4 or other numbers of items in the returned list.

The selection should be done sequentially. For the pattern 'AB' * 4, values whose keys start with 'AB' ('AB', 'ABA', etc.) can be selected. Only after the first value is determined, the next value will be selected to fit in the rest pattern. For example, if the first selected item is 'AB', the next will be 'AB', or 'ABA', while if the first selected item is 'ABA', the next will be 'BA', or 'BAB'. I guess selecting in reverse order is the same, but it has to be sequential.

Comment: "they match the pattern"... or are the keys the pattern and you want to match what you are currently calling "pattern"? So, is the test for instance `"AB" in pattern"` or perhaps `pattern.startswtih("AB")`?

Comment: I think OP means they together makes `"AB" * 4`, for exmaple`'a'` is from `'AB'`, `'f'` is from `'ABA'` and `'l'` is from `'BAB'`. But OP did not mention what happens if `dic` is not complete with all patterns

Comment: This question is not clear at all. what if there is no combination of keys to match the exact pattern ? how often should the func return values (you have one list of length 4 and two with length 3

Comment: The actual dictionary is very large, and there will be restrictions on what can be input as the arguments, so there will be enough values to select. Because the lengths of the keys are different, so the length of the returned list may also be different.

Comment: How do you make sure there will always be enough values? Is this assumed by the input or the function has to control it? For example if you choose AB, AB, ABA, you are left with B which is not in the dict

Comment: It is assumed by the input. The 'time' will be limited to a very small value, and the 'feature' will be AB, BA, ABA, ABB, AAB, BAB, BAA, BBA, and no more. But the actual dictionary is very large.

Comment: one more question. assume, you found a pattern in 3 keys, each key has a list of 4 values. do you want to put those 12 values all in one pot and the func choose 3 or 4 values out of that one big list or is there some rule in which order these 3 lists used to choose a random value

Comment: The selection should be done sequentially. For the pattern 'AB' * 4, values whose keys start with 'AB' ('AB', 'ABA', etc.) can be selected. Only after the first value is determined, the next value will be selected to fit in the rest pattern. For example, if the first selected item is 'AB', the next will be 'AB', or 'ABA', while if the first selected item is 'ABA', the next will be 'BA', or 'BAB'. Selection in reverse order is the same, but it has to be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use some path-search algorithm to find "path" (in this case shortest pattern - but also it can be randomized). In this example I use A*Star:

```py
import random
from heapq import heappop, heappush


def valid_moves(s):
    for k in dic:
        if pattern.startswith("".join(s) + k):
            yield s + tuple([k])


def distance(s):
    return len(pattern) - len("".join(s))


def always(value):
    return lambda *args: value


def a_star(start, moves_func, h_func, cost_func=always(1)):
    """
    Find a shortest sequence of states from start to a goal state
    (a state s with h_func(s) == 0).
    """

    frontier = [
        (h_func(start), start)
    ]  # A priority queue, ordered by path length, f = g + h
    previous = {
        start: None
    }  # start state has no previous state; other states will
    path_cost = {start: 0}  # The cost of the best path to a state.
    Path = lambda s: ([] if (s is None) else Path(previous[s]) + [s])
    while frontier:
        (f, s) = heappop(frontier)
        if h_func(s) == 0:
            return Path(s)
        for s2 in moves_func(s):
            g = path_cost[s] + cost_func(s, s2)
            if s2 not in path_cost or g < path_cost[s2]:
                heappush(frontier, (g + h_func(s2), s2))
                path_cost[s2] = g
                previous[s2] = s


dic = {
    "AB": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "ABA": ["e", "f", "g"],
    "BA": ["h", "i", "j"],
    "BAB": ["k", "l"],
}

pattern = "AB" * 4

path = a_star(tuple(), valid_moves, distance)
final_pattern = path[-1]

out = [random.choice(dic[key]) for key in final_pattern]
print(final_pattern)
print(out)
```

Prints (for example):

```
('ABA', 'BAB', 'AB')
['g', 'l', 'b']
```

---

If you don't want *shortest* pattern but random, you can change `valid_moves()` and `distance()` functions, for example:

```py
def valid_moves(s):
    valid_patterns = []
    for k in dic:
        if pattern.startswith("".join(s) + k):
            valid_patterns.append(s + tuple([k]))

    random.shuffle(valid_patterns)
    yield from valid_patterns


def distance(s):
    return (len(pattern) - len("".join(s))) * random.randint(1, 100)
```

This outputs for example:

```
('AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB')
['c', 'b', 'a', 'b']

# OR

('AB', 'ABA', 'BAB')
['c', 'f', 'l']

...
```

Comment: where can I find the meaning of `cost_func=always(1)` ? Never saw that expression `always(1)` before.

Comment: @Rabinzel That's just `def always(value): return lambda *args: value` (upon calling, it will return a function that will always return 1). To be honest - the actual A*Star implementation isn't mine - I've just changed the `valid_moves()`, `distance()`, ... functions to adapt it to the problem. Other path-searching algorithms can be used of course.

Comment: oh wow, I didn't see the function directly next to it...... ok makes more sense now. thanks^^